# Hotkeys in form inside another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I use hotkeys on a form inside a panel of another form?

Example: I have a form named home and in this form, I have a panel called content and a Button. When I hit the button it's calling a form named Product inside panel content.

The problem is, after-show form product when I hit some key to active form Product keyDown it's called the form home instead.

How can I differ what form keyDown to call?

code to call form:

```
FrmProduct frm = new FrmProduct
{
    TopLevel = false,
    AutoScroll = true,
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

this.PnlContent.Controls.Clear();
this.PnlContent.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Show();
```

this code is on button click inside from Home.

Thanks

Comment: Could you make the requirement a bit clearer? Let's say the shortcut key to catch is `Ctrl+S`, then what should happen if the home form has focus? What should happen if the product form has focus?

Comment: When pressão f1 on form home it Will call the code tô call a form mensioned above. My problema is tô set hotkey on form product inside panel from form Home. The event keydown from form product not fire only from form home. Can I use hotkey from another way?

Comment: It's still unclear for me. Anyway, overriding `ProcessCmdKey` of the top level window is usually the way to go for handling shortcut keys.

Comment: Reza Aghaei how I do this? If the hotkey do not existis in top level form in the keypress  event, I whant tô active keypress of the form call inside the panel of the top leve form

Comment: I'm sorry, the requirement is not clear for me.